# Cannot assign value of type '()' to type '[Category]' in completion handler

Tags: swift, model, alamofire

I have created a Servicemodel class as singleton for getting data back from server( *I use Alamofire*) in my Viewcontroller when I want to use getcategories method I got error **Cannot assign value of type '()' to type '[Category]'**

```
class ServiceModel {

    static let shared = ServiceModel()
    var categories = [Category]()

    func getcategories(completion:@escaping([Category]) -> ()){
        Alamofire.request("http://sample.com/api/getExpertises", 
               method: .post, parameters: ["Id":2]).responseJSON { 
                 (response) in
            if response.result.isSuccess{

                if let data = response.data{
                    let experts = JSON(data)
                    for i in experts{
                        let id = i.1["id"].string!;
                        let title = i.1["expertise"].string!


             self.categories.append(Category(id:Int(id)!,title: title))
                    }
                    completion(self.categories);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**and in ViewController :**

```
    categories = ServiceModel.shared.getcategories(completion: { 
 //in this line i get error 
        (Categories) in
        print(Categories)
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error says that return of `getcategories` is `()` which can't be assigned to an array `categories` of type `Category` , so  Inside `ViewController` Should be like

```
var categories = [Category]()

ServiceModel.shared.getcategories { res in
    print(res) 
    self.categories = res
    // or 
    print(ServiceModel.shared.categories)
}
```

Comment: I have Defined     var categories = [Category]() inside my ViewController and tested code like you have written but i'm still getting same error !!!!!

Comment: what a mistake , i have forgot that method doesn't return anything ,Ha Ha Ha .

Comment: I removed var categories in ViewController And code works , Thanks Sh_Khan